# How to make a list of random ASCII letters and digits?

Tags: python, random

I would like to generate a list of random numbers and letters.

I managed to make this:

```
def rand_num():
  
    while True:
        random_char= random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits)
    
        random_lst= [random_char]
```

but when I want to print this `random_lst` I get an output like this:

```
['W']
['i']
['P']
['6']
['P']
['B']
['d']
['f']
['n']
['j']
```

instead of:

`['W','i','P'`.... and so on

What should I do? Is `.choice` the wrong function in this case?

Answer (score 5):

Try this for a list of length 10:

```
random_list = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for n in xrange(10)]
```

Or this for a string of length 10:

```
random_string = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for n in xrange(10))
```

Answer (score 4):

You should have this instead:

```
random_lst.append(random_char)
```

Comment: silly me :[ I did try that but I forgot to put an empty list outside the while :D.

Comment: @user1509923 Oops! The other answer is cool too because it uses a list comprehension. Check it out.